# Data & Analytics advanced contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, quote, pricing

anyone knows what is "data & Analytics advanced contacts"? we find this item in the product bundle from Marketing Cloud product list, what kind of functionalities it provides? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naming is a bit misleading. This is actually the pricing for Audience Builder according to our MC account executive.

Comment: Thank you Stephan, your reply helps a lot! we'll double check with our AE on this

Comment: Glad it helped. Please rate and mark as solved when you got confirmation from your AE